# Determine which files take up the most space in zip file

Tags: zip, archiving

I have a zip file with many directories and files inside of it.  I'd like to determine which files are taking up the most compressed space in the archive.  Anyone know of a handy mechanism to do this?

Comment: I can only think of shoving `unzip -v` through awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any typical zip utility such as [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) will display the file system within the zip file in a flat manner; versus hierarchical.

This will allow you to sort the files based on size providing the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I tried that, but in 7-zip the packed size column shows all 0's except for one file which shows the entire packed file.  I an view and sort on the original sizes of the files, but that's not helpful in this case.  Do you think there's something odd with my version of 7-zip?

Comment: actually just tried it again.  Looks like 7-zip compression doesn't behave well for viewing compressed files, but when I zip with a regular deflate method in .zip it's fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rich Modify the view; View -> Flat View...then look at the Size column.